# How to trigger swiperefreshlayout in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, swiperefreshlayout

I want to trigger my `SwipeRefreshLayout` in the event `onCreateView` of my `MainFragment`.
What I want to do is start downloading the information in the event `onCreateView` and at the same time I show the SwipeRefreshLayout refreshing. Any ideas?

Here is my code in my Java code in `MainFragment`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        SwipeRefreshLayout swpRfrshLyt= (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swpRfrshLyt);

        swpRfrshLyt.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.holo_blue_light,
                R.color.holo_green_light,
                R.color.holo_orange_light,
                R.color.holo_red_light);

        swpRfrshLyt.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swpRfrshLyt.setRefreshing(true);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Here is my `fragment_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swpRfrshLyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstvw_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I am using Android Studio, here is my build gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
}
```

I have installed `Android SDK Build Tools 21.0.2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SwipeRefreshLayout trigger programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587925/swiperefreshlayout-trigger-programmatically)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a better solution to achieve this by using the following:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
});
```

Here mSwipeRefreshLayout is the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. If you simply call:

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

it wont trigger the circle to animate, so by adding the above line you just make a delay in the UI thread so that it shows the circle animation inside the UI thread.

By calling `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)` the   OnRefreshListener will also get executed so after the task end just add `mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)` to stop the circle animation.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,you save my day !

Answer (score 5):

After calling `swpRfrshLyt.setRefreshing(true);` you need to actually call the function that does the refresh. It does not get called automatically. Better yet, create a function that does both for you.

**UPDATE**

**DO NOT USE THIS SOLUTION - read below**

The spinner is behind the action bar so you have to push it down.

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int height = size.y;
    getSwipeRefreshLayout().setProgressViewOffset(false, 200, height / 9);
```

**UPDATE 2**

I would no longer recommend my above solution. The better solution is:

```
getSwipeRefreshLayout().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        getSwipeRefreshLayout().setRefreshing(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: What I wanted to say is that the method swpRfrshLyt.setRefreshing(true);doesnt work for me.

Comment: It does work. The spinner is showing up behind the action bar. Ill update my answer.

Comment: It's working! Where should I call swpRfrshLyt.setRefreshing(true) without hardcoring the offset?

Comment: You can just call a function to do what I did above at the beginning of the activity. Then do the `setRefreshing` anytime you need it. And please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to accepted answer use the following code as well:

```
swipeContainer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

**Explanation** I implemented the solution (using fragments) but after the swipeReferesh started it never went away even on calling `swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);` so had to implement the code given above which solved my problem. any more ideas why this happens are most welcome.

Regards,

**P.S.:** `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1`