# SwipeRefreshLayout don't call refresh listener

Tags: android

I'm using `SwipeRefreshLayout` and want to set it refreshing after I create the `Activity`, but the `setRefreshing(true)` do not work. So I find this question in SO:[SwipeRefreshLayout setRefreshing not showing indicator initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858692/swiperefreshlayout-setrefreshing-not-showing-indicator-initially).

I choose to override SwipeRefreshLayout to store local refreshing flag:

```
public class MyRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    public MyRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private boolean mMeasured = false;
    private boolean mPreMeasureRefreshing = false;

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (!mMeasured) {
            mMeasured = true;
            setRefreshing(mPreMeasureRefreshing);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void setRefreshing(boolean refreshing) {
        if (mMeasured) {
            super.setRefreshing(refreshing);
        } else {
            mPreMeasureRefreshing = refreshing;
        }
    }
}
```

It will refresh after I create activity but the `OnRefreshListener` do not be called. Here is my init code:

```
mRefreshLayout = (MyRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refresh_layout);
mRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.holo_blue_dark, R.color.holo_blue_light, R.color.holo_green_light, R.color.holo_green_light);
mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
          mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});

mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
```

I can't find relate question , please help , thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found that I misunderstood the `OnRefreshListener`. The doc says:

> Classes that wish to be notified when the swipe gesture correctly triggers a refresh should implement this interface.

So If I call `mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);`. It is not a swipe gesture , the listener won't be called!

Comment: Hai.. I am also getting same problem.. how u solved this

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in Min2's answer for the solution on how to call the listener

[SwipeRefreshLayout trigger programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587925/swiperefreshlayout-trigger-programmatically)