# SwipeRefreshLayout OnRefreshListener not called when registered in onCreate

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I'm trying to use `SwipeRefreshLayout` but when I set the `OnRefreshListener` in the `onCreate()` method of the activity, it does not get called when swiping. Looking at the example code this does appear to be the proper way to do things. When I register the listener at a later point, like in `onPostCreate()` or at the press of a button, it does get called on swipe. What am I missing?

**MessageListActivity.java**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_list);

    final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Swiped for refresh!");
        }
    });
}
```

**activity_message_list.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout">
        <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your `MessageListActivity` extending `FragmentActivity` or another type of activity ?

Comment: You can find this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587925/swiperefreshlayout-trigger-programmatically/35621309#35621309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I made a rather silly mistake. I was calling setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_list) somewhere after the onCreate, causing the resource to be inflated again.